# PyCharm autocomplete (hints?) not working for only one package

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with Excel files and I'm using the `openpyxl` package. I'm also making a GUI so I'm using the `PyQt5` package. When I type something like this:

```
label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Text", window)
```

as soon as I type `QtWidgets.` I get options for what to do next, and I know what I have available.

I want to do the same with the openpyxl package, but it's not working. I have tried stuff like this:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for table in ws.tables:
    print(table)
```

When I type `ws.`, there's no "tables" option initially, unless I have already used it in my own code somewhere before. I want to know what options I have when I type in `ws.`, but it's just not showing anything.

Examples:

[It doesn't work with the openpyxl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDSp.png)

[It works with the PyQt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcie8.png)

Comment: The screenshot you shared doesn't show how you import openpyxl. Also, you haven't told us enough about your environment - what kind of environment are you running, are you sure openpyxl is properly installed in it and is PyCharm using it, and what version of Python, openpyxl and PyCharm are you on?

Comment: I installed openpyxl by clicking alt + enter and clicking install package. I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: Please read the comment carefully. How do you *import* openpyxl? Your code doesn't show. *What kind of environment* are you running, you're not saying. We know you're using PyCharm, but *what version*? And what *version of Python*? And what *version of openpyxl*?

Comment: Sorry, import like this: "import openpyxl". Environment PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3. Python version 3.10.8. openpyxl version 3.0.10 EDIT: I'm sure that it works properly as the functions work as intended, but the autocomplete isn't working.

Comment: It looks like this is the result of the way the `openpyxl` package is written. Looking at the source, PyCharm can't really get at the definition of the worksheet to generate the hints, even though `wb['Sheet1']` will always be a `openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet`. Even explicitly defining `ws` as being of that type doesn't allow PyCharm to resolve the attributes before runtime. I'm not sure there's a solution here that doesn't involve contacting the maintainers of `openpyxl` and pointing out that they could add some code or documentation that would resolve this.